# How to pass data from web to android app?

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc

I have a web page which I use to display in an android application. By clicking on print button of the web page, I am generating an image and storing it to a shareable location on a server.

I am using Zebra Printer for printing. So after the image is stored on the server, I need to pass the image location to the android app. The Android app will pass a message to the Zebra Printer for printing.

I thought to pass image location through **PUBNUB Notification**. But I want to know other workaround as PUBNUB fails sometimes.

Does anybody know other ways?

Comment: you can also try with GCM

Comment: Any special reason for using pubnub? rather than gcm?

Comment: @AjayPandya I don't have any idea about GCM

Comment: @AjayPandya do have any idea about how we can trigger broadcast Reciever from a php file?